# Making a classic javascript 3rd party app work within an existing react/node app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app that does video chat already built in react/node.

I am trying to add a feature that opens up a shared whiteboard that the participants in the video chat can use.

I did some research and AwwApp is the one I like the best for this shared whiteboard functionality.

AwwApp does not have react specific code examples or modules.  However, they do provide a straightforward widget that uses a .js file they host.

I am trying to implement this classic javascript widget into my existing react app and running into some issues - likely due to something simple that I'm just missing.

Here's the simple AwwApp quick start with the js file to include and how to call it the classic way: https://awwapp.com/apis/V2/docs/

Here is the code from my "AwwBoard.js" file that I am using to create a component that renders the whiteboard anywhere I want to import it and return  in react:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import Script from 'react-load-script'

// Get cookie for meeting room that this whiteboard instance will appear in.  Will be used after I get whiteboard working.
const cookieMgr = new Cookies();
const room = cookieMgr.get('room');

// The main AwwApp external javascript file to include, I use react-load-script to load it below
const awwAppScript = 'https://awwapp.com/static/widget/js/aww3.min.js';

// Create a React component I can display using <AwwBoard /> anywhere I want a whieboard to appear
class AwwBoard extends Component {
    handleScriptCreate() {
        this.setState({ scriptLoaded: false });
    };

    handleScriptError() {
        this.setState({ scriptError: true });
    };

    handleScriptLoad() {
        this.setState({ scriptLoaded: true });
    };

    // Function I created to render the board. Per https://awwapp.com/apis/V2/docs/ - should embed the whiteboard widget in the div with id aww-wrapper below
    handleBoardRender() {
        var aww = new AwwBoard('#aww-wrapper', {
        });

        return aww;
    };

    render() {
        return (

            <div id="aww-wrapper">
                <Script
                    url={awwAppScript}
                    onCreate={this.handleScriptCreate.bind(this)}
                    onError={this.handleScriptError.bind(this)}
                    onLoad={this.handleScriptLoad.bind(this)}
                />

                {this.handleBoardRender()}

            </div>    
        )
    };
};


export default AwwBoard;
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  I'm sure there is an easy way to do this, I'm just not seeing it after doing some of my own trial and error.

Thanks!

Comment: you need to create a wrapper component - that adds your 3p component to the page and mediates control messages.  when your wrapper component renders it will add the 3p component in its render section, and configure it with your props or state it was provided with.  If it is JS based you react component acts as an anchor, and your componentDidMount as the initiator

Comment: Thanks!  that makes sense conceptually, just not exactly clear how to do it specifically.  Mind giving a code example by any chance?

Comment: google maps is now supported as a react application, but there was a time when it wasn't.  There are many examples of using this technique with the pre-react version.  This is the approach i would take. Here is one such example:  https://blog.vanila.io/writing-a-google-maps-react-component-fae411588a91
 notice how the Container (the wrapper component) has a single div, which is where the 3p app is bound to the DOM- let me know how you get on.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!!